# How to decode body (ByteBuffer) to Content in Vapor 4?

Tags: json, swift, decode, vapor

I can easily decode response.content as it's described in Vapor docs, when ResponseReceipt conforms to Content protocol here.

```
let receipt = try? response.content.decode(ResponseReceipt.self)
```

But it's not that easy to understand how to decode response.body using Vapor's tools as it's ByteBuffer. How can I decode response.body in the similar native to Vapor manner?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all it is important to understand that ByteBuffer is kinda collection of bytes, so you could just read bytes from it and try to initialize `Data` like this

```swift
guard let byteBuffer = req.body.data else { throw Abort(.badRequest) }
let data = Data(buffer: byteBuffer)
let receipt = try JSONDecoder().decode(ResponseReceipt.self, from: data)
```

or like this

```swift
guard let byteBuffer = response.body.data else { throw Abort(.badRequest) }
guard let data = byteBuffer.getData(at: 0, length: byteBuffer.readableBytes) else { throw Abort(.badRequest) }
let receipt = try JSONDecoder().decode(ResponseReceipt.self, from: data)
```

But with Vapor you have two more convenient ways to decode byte buffer

Choose which one you like more

```swift
guard let byteBuffer = response.body.data else { throw Abort(.badRequest) }
let receipt = try JSONDecoder().decode(ResponseReceipt.self, from: byteBuffer)
```

one more

```swift
guard let byteBuffer = response.body.data else { throw Abort(.badRequest) }
guard let receipt = try byteBuffer.getJSONDecodable(ResponseReceipt.self, at: 0, length: byteBuffer.readableBytes)
```

and one more

```swift
guard let byteBuffer = response.body.data else { throw Abort(.badRequest) }
guard let receipt = try byteBuffer.getJSONDecodable(ResponseReceipt.self, decoder: JSONDecoder(), at: 0, length: byteBuffer.readableBytes)
```

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping Vapor has its own mechanism for that and decoding to Content directly with better decoding algorithms. I mean was hoping it will be able to decode "1" to Bool true etc and avoid long manual decoding initialisers in my Decodable structs. Anyway, you are getting +1 as I will shorten my code a bit by skipping converting ByteBuffer to Data))